# How to get last 5 unique product IDs?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table of orders. Each order is linked to one or more basket items.

Basic code:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders o JOIN OrderItems oi ON o.OrderNumber = oi.OrderNumber
```

I can limit to the last 5 items by doing this:

```
ORDER BY oi.CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 5
```

However, in some cases the user has placed multiple orders across the same products. e.g.

```
OrderNo   ItemNo   ProductId
  1          1         70
  1          2         20
  2          1         80
  2          2         30
  3          1         10
  4          1         90
  5          1         10
  6          1         40
  7          1         50
  8          1        100
  9          1         10
 10          1         30
 11          1         10
 12          1         60
```

If I get the last five items, I'd end up with 60, 10, 30, 10, 100. What I actually want is to get the last 5 unique product IDs - so that'd be 60, 10, 30, 100, 50. What would the SQL for this be?

**Edited**

If I use GROUP BY I get 60, 100, 50, 40, 90. Where is 30?

Comment: the problem is that `GROUP BY` is somehow executed before `ORDER BY` takes place.

Comment: please see my changes to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select ProductID from
(select ProductID, max(OrderNo)
 from Orders
 group by ProductID
 order by 2 desc) sq
limit 5
```

Answer (score 1):

USE `

> GROUP BY Product ORDER BY Order DESC LIMIT 5

`

Comment: This seems to work if it's a small dataset but isn't working for the real data I'm using. I'll update the sample data I've included above and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `GROUP BY Product`

```
SELECT * 
FROM Orders o 
JOIN OrderItems oi ON o.OrderNumber = oi.OrderNumber 
GROUP BY o.Product 
ORDER BY oi.CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: If I do that I get 60, 100, 50, 40, 90. That is not the last 5 product IDs. I updated the data so there are fewer 10s in the list, otherwise the GROUP BY does work in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: the problem is that MySql does `group by` before `order by`. A trick to fool it is:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
   SELECT
      O.OrderNumber, 
      oi.ItemNo, 
      oi.Productid
   FROM 
      orders o 
   JOIN 
      OrderItems oi ON o.OrderNumber = oi.OrderNumber
   ORDER BY 
      oi.CreateDate DESC
) AS fool_mysql
GROUP BY 
   ProductId
LIMIT 5;
```

That is, do the ordering BEFORE the grouping.

Comment: Thanks, but even with DISTINCT and GROUP BY I get 60, 100, 50, 40, 90. I would expect 30 to be in the list as it appears third from bottom in the table.